# get_option include <br /> in my adsense

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, jquery, javascript

As title said I saved in wp-options -> option_value a adsense code but when I try to display to website in the code I get some

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--<br />google_ad_client = \"ca-pub-\";<br />/* Header all pages */<br />google_ad_slot = \"xxxxx\";<br />google_ad_width = 728;<br />google_ad_height = 90;<br />//--><br /></script><br /><script type=\"text/javascript\"<br />src=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\"><br /></script>"
```

Why do I get this?

Comment: Post the code that saves the option, and the code that displays it, please.

Comment: <br /> shows up when display the adsense code. I guess it is wpautop